# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'typeof' for dynamic importing

Tags: typescript, graphql

Kind of a head-scratcher for me on this. I could do ts-ignore but I don't really want to. I just have a helper func that dynamically imports a query and uses that with graphql useQuery but the key is being interpreted as a string. It errors on `Queries[gqlQueryName]`, I know you can do obj: {[key: any]: any} but I dont know if that applies to this.

```
import * as Queries from '../graphql/queries';
import { useQuery } from '@apollo/client';

const UseGetQuery = (queryStr: string) => {
    const gqlQueryName = 'QUERY_' + queryStr.toUpperCase().split(' ').join('_');

    const { data, loading, refetch } = useQuery(Queries[gqlQueryName]);

    return { data, loading, refetch };
};

export default UseGetQuery;
```

Not sure if this helps but my queries file looks like this:

```
export const QUERY_POPULAR_MOVIES = gql`
    query getPopularMovies {
        popularMovies {
            results {
                original_title
                overview
            }
        }
    }
`;

export const QUERY_SEARCHED_MOVIES = gql`
    query getSearchMovies($q: String!) {
        searchedMovies(q: $q) {
            results {
                original_title
                vote_average
                id
            }
        }
    }
`;
```

and queryStr is like 'searched movies'

Answer (score 2):

I guess, your `Queries` object looks like this:

```js
const Queries = {
  QUERY_PRODUCT_ONE_WITH_PRICE: "...",
  QUERY_CUSTOMER_TWO_WITH_LAST_NAME: "..."
}
```

(Keys matter, value is not relevant here)

so you want `queryStr` to either be `product one with price` or `customer two with last name` if I understand the `const gqlQueryName = ....` correctly.

You can achieve this using some mapped types with conditional types in TS:

```js
import * as Queries from '../graphql/queries';
type IQueries = typeof Queries;

type Replace<S extends string> = S extends `${infer A}_${infer B}` ? Replace<`${A} ${B}`> : S


type AllowedQueryNames =  keyof IQueries extends `QUERY_${infer S}` ? Lowercase<Replace<S>> : never

const UseGetQuery = (queryStr: AllowedQueryNames) => { 
  // ...
}
```

Some examples:

```js
const x: AllowedQueryNames = "product one with price"; // OK
const y: AllowedQueryNames = "customer two with last name";  // OK
const a: AllowedQueryNames = "order by id" // Compile error
```

TypeScript Playground: http://surl.li/cuyjb

Not sure, if that detected all cases, but it should work.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry, I didnt think it would be helpful to include my queries file but ill add it now. But that does seem to work, not gonna lie, it seems like alot of typescript magic to me but this great stuff to learn more about. Thank you so much!

Comment: Yes! TypeScript is very powerfull but can also be kind of magic! Just in case some is interested in, I also added a CodeSandbox example with your (simplified) queries file: https://codesandbox.io/s/blazing-frog-13p9je?file=/src/UseGetQuery.ts